# Maximum information Rate?

Tags: signal-processing, sampling

It is said that we can transmit at the most twice as many bits information per second as the transmission channel has the bandwidth. For example, 1 kHz bandwidth allows max 2kbit/s, if that rule is used. What is the theory behind this rule? Does Nyquist's sampling rate theorem imply it somehow? If yes, then how? I cannot see the connection

Comment: Who says this? How much information is two, anyway?

Comment: I Found this in the Textbook written by BP Lathi.

Comment: Each sample is considered as an information

Comment: There's certainly no limit on bandwidth that I'm aware of, anyway. So either the textbook is wrong or you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: This is the same as asking why transmission of Rb bits/seconds requires a minimum of Rb/2 Hz bandwidth

Comment: *It is said that we can transmit at the most two information per second* That makes little sense. What is "two information", two bits ? What prevents you to look up Nyquist's theorem on other sources, like Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Comment: In English, "information" is an unnumbered noun, like "stuff".  You cannot have "two information", just as you can't have one, or twenty.  You can have "lots of information", or "little information" -- but you can't have two of it.  If the book you're quoting is in English, I suggest you take a picture of the passage and post it.  If it's not, please make another attempt at translation.

Comment: You must be able to sample faster than information is coming in by at least 2x bits/sec. That is why 'oversampling' is so popular as you go way beyond the Nyquist limit so it is not an issue. Then you can use analog out-of-band filters so an ADC sees only that which has to be processed. It seems that you need to study much more to wrap your head around this issue.

Comment: I tried to fix the text of your question. Please, revert it to original if it's now incorrect. Please, confirm, if the edit is ok. The original is still visible because it has got so many comments. Removing the original isn't polite.

Comment: @user287001 thank you for the edit.

Comment: Please provide a more extensive citation from the book written by Lathi. Also, please provide full title, edition, page number in book. I think you may be misinterpreting what Lathi wrote, or you may have omitted some context or assumptions that are relevant to this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"transmission of Rb bits/seconds requires a minimum of Rb/2 Hz bandwidth" - that's an old rule of thumb which has been used in telegraph system design. Harry Nyquist has found it, but that's not his famous sampling rate theorem.

The rule can be seen to be true by comparing the -3dB bandwidth of a lowpass filter and how short pulses that filter can output. Formally one should calculate the effective length of the impulse response of a lowpass filter with certain effective bandwidth. With some integral calculus one gets the following ratio:

*If a filter has bandwidth =B, then its outputs pulses have width equal or more than 1/(2B). The minimum is the width of the impulse response.*

Nyquist's sampling rate theorem isn't closely related with this rule. It also has number 1/2 and frequencies, but it handles different things. It's a good thing you haven't seen any connection.

**Not asked:** Nyquist's sampling rate theorem can be easily understood by considering sampling as a special case of mixing

So, if pulses which have length T in the channel output, are sent as densely as possible, the bitrate is 1/T, when one pulse presents one bit (= 1 or 0). The needed channel bandwidth is the bitrate/2.

One should notice that having BW=bitrate/2 distorts pulses remarkably, but it can still allow detecting the existence and polarity of the pulses and that's enough for binary transmission.

Rule "channel bandwidth must be at least bitrate/2 in one bit per pulse systems" was a quarter of a century enough for understanding practical telegraph system bandwidth needs when there was no remarkable noise.

Claude Shannon and his colleaque broke this all about 70 years ago by publishing the mathematical theory of communication. Their most revolutionary idea was the mathematically solid statistical (=probability theory based) model for "what is information".

Comment: Could you explain why you say this isn't related to the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem? Are you perhaps talking about multi-channel modulation? This answer seems a bit unclear as to what specific part of it is actually the answer to the question.

Comment: I might just need to sleep, but shouldn't it be "Rb/2 bit/s requires Rb Hz bandwidth"? (incidentally, while it's not hard to follow or anything, I should point out that "rule of thumb" is the usual phrasing at least in american english; I've never heard "thumb rule")

Comment: @Hearth thumb is fixed. pulse which has length=T really needs approximately B=1/(2T)=0,5/T . T=1/bitrate in one bit per one pulse  systems. B=0,5/(1/bitrate)=0,5 * (bitrate) = bitrate/2.

Answer (score 1):

If the "information" is binary ( like the telegraph 100 yrs ago), then with some constraints defined by Harry Nyquist in 1928, you must sample **at least 2 times per cycle** for the smallest period of binary information to recover it.

This is because AC has 2 polarities so two samples are needed to detect this smallest cycle interval.

A filter to block signals above 1/2 the sampling rate is needed to prevent errors are degrade S/N ratio so often <=1/3 of the sampling rate is used as it is impossible to have no phase shift in a filter that passes signals  up to 1/2 the sampling rate and blocks noise above this.

Binary information needs a ratio of sampling rate,\$f_s\$ to signal Bandwidth,BW  \$f_s/BW=2\$

Analog information with higher resolution than 2 needs a much higher ratio for \$f_s/BW>>2\$
 Have you noticed that in DSO scopes?